Trouble with disappearing/transparent mesh objects
I’m pretty new to Blender. Currently I’m having an issue where I’m trying to create a domed cylinder that sits above the plane of my main object. So I had to extrude it up a little before adding the bevel. But then it disappears? I can see the mesh points still when in edit mode but completely invisible when I go to object mode.
If it matters the next step is I need to cut it in half and bevel that edge as well before connecting it to the main object. (Profile pic is what I’m creating for 3D print)
A couple of the things I’ve tried are hitting the Numpad button and Alt+H.
Using Blender 2.9 on a 2011 MacBook running masOS High Sierra.



Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

First guess is a modifier such as Remesh that is deleting disconnected pieces. Do you have any modifiers on there?
